# How to remove - before the text -450

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

i have a textbox showing -450 as output but i want it displays out put as 450 by removing - from 450 ....

Answer (score 7):

`string text = TextBox.Text.Replace("-", "");`

`string text = TextBox.Text.TrimStart('-');`

`string text = TextBox.Text.Remove(0, 1);`